# Galleriffic with lightBox

Tags: javascript, jquery, lightbox

For the relaunch of my clients site (craft2eu.net) I need to integrate [Galleriffic](http://www.twospy.com/galleriffic/) with a [lightBox](http://leandrovieira.com/projects/jquery/lightbox/). I know there is [GallerificPlus](http://mattgifford.co.uk/projects/gallerificPlus/), but it is based on an old version of Galleriffic which brings some things I don't like. For example the invalid attributes, etc.

How do I integrate the current version of Galleriffic (2.0 at the time of writing this)?

I already followed [trent's suggestion](http://trentacular.com/2009/10/galleriffic-2-0/#comment-935) that can be found in the Galleriffic blog comments without any success.

Comment: Hope I got the links right. Can you check

Comment: Please add info what you mean by "integrating galleriffic with lightbox"

Answer (score 1):

I finally managed to make lightbox work with gallerfic. I'm using [shadowbox](http://www.shadowbox-js.com), base/standard for images, including CSS support.

For my client's needs, it was OK to have an additional link below the image. To that end,
I simply used the "download" div to add a link to the same image as shown in the image-wrapper div. (I'm using PHP/MySQL to extract images from the db, so I have a loop in the `<li>` section).

In the first straight-up implementation, the link would work, but the lightbox would not show up. I would only get the link to follow the `src` and display the image in the same window, although I had specific the `rel="lightbox"` in the link.
I realized that when hitting the back button and clicking the link again, the lightbox would actually work! After some research, I deducted that it was a preload image issue. I hence just added an `img` tag above the ligthbox enabled link in my download `div` with a `width="0"` and `height="0"`, plus `border="0"` this actually loads the image on the page, but in hidden mode.

Also, to circumvent shadowbox loading to early and being unloaded by gallerific, I added `onmouseover="shadowbox.init();"` to the download div, so that it would load again after an image load in the image-wrapper.

I admit it's a little bit of cheating, but it's working! Let me know if it works for you