# Gallerific and lightbox modal

Tags: json, flickr, shadowbox

Hi I have a problem with shadow box not loading after galleriffic has changed image.

The same problem found here: [Galleriffic with lightBox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1868968/galleriffic-with-lightbox/14689002#14689002)

have a look t my half working example here:
http://tgp2.1.timgodwinphotography.co.uk/gallery/albums/album0.php#gallery

where you can see the link on the bottom (view large) should open a light box.  It does but only for the first image and not after navigating with gallerific.

```
<div class="download" onmouseover="Shadowbox.init();">
<a href="http://#" rel="shadowbox[album]">View Large</a>    
</div>
```

The source of the modal is pulled in by jquery via json feed from flickr

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found a solution over on the shadow box forums:

http://shadowbox.1309102.n2.nabble.com/Shadowbox-in-Galleriffic-tp6158381.html

basically adding js to the anchor in order to ensure shadow box reloads each time gallerific does:

```
<div class="download">
<a href="http://#" rel="shadowbox" onclick="Shadowbox.open(this, {type:'img', gallery:'gallery', displayCounter:'true', counterType:'skip', continuous:'true', title:'Redwood Press', content:'/getattachment/cdef7c0d-b0e9-4d64-91cd-95c894553d23/Redwood-Press.jpg'}); return false;">View Large</a>  
</div>
```

all credit to QuickPaw

see 
http://tgp2.1.timgodwinphotography.co.uk/gallery/albums/album0.php

for working example